# How to propagate values from one row in a pandas Dataframe to all other rows

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, vectorization

I need to set all rows in a dataframe based on the adjacent row on the side closest to some index. The context is the dataframe is full of estimates, and rows can be corrected based on a row next to them, so starting from the best row good results could work there way out to the edges.

Example code which demonstrates the desired outcome:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.linspace(1, 7, 7), columns=['guess'])
correct_row_index = 3
df['cumulative_error'] = 0
for i in range(correct_row_index - 1, -1, -1):
    df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('cumulative_error')] = abs(df['guess'].iloc[i] - df['guess'].iloc[i + 1]) + df['cumulative_error'].iloc[i + 1]
for i in range(correct_row_index + 1, len(df), 1):
    df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('cumulative_error')] = abs(df['guess'].iloc[i] - df['guess'].iloc[i - 1]) +   df['cumulative_error'].iloc[i - 1]
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I will be dealing with large dataset and would prefer to totally avoid python loops

Comment: Might be able to do something along the lines of `df.guess.moving().apply( lambda x:  some function involving cumsum)`  Do one forward looking, one backward looking.  Not sure if it would necessarily be any better or faster though

Comment: What is the moving() function?

Comment: sorry, meant `rolling()`  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#rolling-windows  Note that this changed from a function to method starting in version 0.18.0

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that is functionally very similar to the original approach, but with indexing on the entire array in two parts in vectorized fashion instead of per-element basis -

```
# Perform the subtractions for the two parts, keeping cumsumming for later on
p1 = np.abs(df['guess'][:correct_row_index] - df['guess'][correct_row_index])
p2 = np.abs(df['guess'][correct_row_index:] - df['guess'][correct_row_index])

# Perform cumsum, concatenate and store into the output column
df['cumulative_error'] = np.concatenate((p1[::-1].cumsum()[::-1],p2.cumsum()))
```

**Runtime test**

Function definitions :

```
def original_app(df,correct_row_index):
    df['cumulative_error'] = 0
    for i in range(correct_row_index - 1, -1, -1):
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('cumulative_error')] = \
        abs(df['guess'].iloc[i] - df['guess'].iloc[correct_row_index]) + \
        df['cumulative_error'].iloc[i + 1]

    for i in range(correct_row_index + 1, len(df), 1):
        df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('cumulative_error')] = \
        abs(df['guess'].iloc[i] - df['guess'].iloc[correct_row_index]) + \
        df['cumulative_error'].iloc[i - 1]

    return df

def vectorized_app(df,correct_row_index):
    p1 = np.abs(df['guess'][:correct_row_index] - df['guess'][correct_row_index])
    p2 = np.abs(df['guess'][correct_row_index:] - df['guess'][correct_row_index])
    df['cumulative_error'] = np.concatenate((p1[::-1].cumsum()[::-1],p2.cumsum()))
    return df
```

Timings -

```
In [304]: # Inputs
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,2001), columns=['guess'])
     ...: correct_row_index = 1000
     ...: 
     ...: # Save copies for benchmarking
     ...: df_copy1 = df.copy()
     ...: df_copy2 = df.copy()
     ...: 

In [305]: %timeit original_app(df_copy1,correct_row_index)
1 loops, best of 3: 945 ms per loop

In [306]: %timeit vectorized_app(df_copy2,correct_row_index)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop
```

Comment: This solves the example code, before I edited it, but sidesteps my real problem. Rows can only be calculated from rows next to them, and must wait for those adjacent rows to be calculated first.

Comment: @Mark So, I assumed the dependency is `cumsum` and that's what the solution solves it for. For any other dependency, the solution won't work. Sorry.